# AJAX response with fatal error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm making the following ajax request.

```
$.ajax({                                      
            url: '../app/Models/UserFiles.php',                       
            data:'data',
            dataType: 'json',    
            success: function(data)          
            {
                var id = data[0];             
                var name = data[1];
                $('#results').append("id: " +id+ "name: "+name);        
            } 
      });
```

After checking the response with FireBug I noticed this response:

> **Fatal error**:  Class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model' not found in **C:\xampp\htdocs\bluedrive
>   \drive\app\Models\UserFiles.php** on line **6**

I can't find anything wrong with UserFiles.php. This actually is the file:

```
<?php
  namespace App\Models;
  use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Auth;
  use App\Models\Filecontent;
  class UserFiles extends Model{
    protected $table = 'files';

    public function getUserFiles(){
      $userid = Auth::id();
      $getFiles = Filecontent::where('userid', $userid)->get();
      foreach($getFiles as $getFile) {
          $result = $getFile;
          echo json_encode($result);
      }
     }   
   } ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is a fatal error in your PHP, not your AJAX. AJAX is jsut showing you the output of the PHP. The PHP is not seeing the Eloquent Model

Comment: drive\app\ lowercase "a" and you're using namespace App and `../app/`. If on *nix that's case-sensitive.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah, I know but the code works fine if the method is just called in some other php file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm running Win8.1 ; The lowercase shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Ok, I had to ask. Which is why I mentioned "if on *nix" - error reporting on? if not http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You are abusing Laravel. This function should be in a controller, then define a route for that function which should be the url for your AJAX request. The laravel framewrk is not bootstrapipng with the way you are following. Read about Laravel [lifecycle](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/lifecycle) and [routing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing)

Comment: @Vikas How should the url look like?

Comment: It can be something like this: 
Route::get('getuserfiles', 'UserFilesController@getUserFiles'); . In the AJAX request, then you would use it like this:  url: '[http://localhost/getuserfiles](http://localhost/getuserfiles)'

Comment: @Vikas I mean in the AJAX url, not in the Route.php

Comment: In the AJAX request, you would use it like this:  url: '[http://localhost/getuserfiles](http://localhost/getuserfiles)' or if your application home url is different then localhost, then it would change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The url in ajax call should be something like this:

```
...
url: <?php echo URL::route('route_to_handle_posted_data.post') ?>
...
```

Or, if the ajax call is in a js file you can define a

```
var route_to_post = <?php echo URL::route('route_to_handle_posted_data.post') ?>;
```

somewhere in templates.

Comment: I still get in the response a php Fatal Error. The interesting thing is if I call the method getUserFiles() in another php ifle everything works just file. But when calling it with ajax request the file gives me an error...

Comment: You can define a post route that points to a controller method in which you return the model method. This is a suggestion.